# implementation of firebase in php: finding token in firebase

Tags: php, database, firebase

i am trying to implement firebase with php, here is a link that I found:

https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

and this is an example.

```
const DEFAULT_URL = 'https://kidsplace.firebaseio.com/';
const DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'MqL0c8tKCtheLSYcygYNtGhU8Z2hULOFs9OKPdEp';
const DEFAULT_PATH = '/firebase/example';

$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);

// --- storing an array ---
$test = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "i_love" => "lamp",
    "id" => 42
);
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/' . $dateTime->format('c'), $test);

// --- storing a string ---
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/contact001', "John Doe");

// --- reading the stored string ---
$name = $firebase->get(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/contact001');
```

And here is my version of the same code:

```
<?php

include 'firebaseLib.php';

const DEFAULT_URL = "https://third-try-dae0a.firebaseio.com";
const DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'AIzaSyDeGfW4hnT3a6AXDevJMhb4Pi1eMWQ7yvc';
const DEFAULT_PATH = '/third-try-dae0a';


$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);

// --- storing an array ---
$test = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "i_love" => "lamp",
    "id" => 42
);
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/' . $dateTime->format('c'), $test);

// --- storing a string ---
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/contact001', "John Doe");

// --- reading the stored string ---
$name = $firebase->get(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/contact001');

echo "done";



 ?>
```

my code doesn't work...

[image: this is where i found my DEFAULT_TOKEN]

I just want a quick explanation of where I find the DEFAULT_TOKEN

and what about the DEFAULT_PATH ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) DEFAULT_PATH**

Default path is your main project path. When you create new project on firebase. And when you will click on it you will get the path for it. Which is like: `https://your_project_name-xxx.firebaseio.com`

**2)DEFAULT_TOKEN**

Steps to get token from firebase console

->login open and open fire base console and select project

->Go to project `setting` from setting icon

->select `serviceaccounts` from menu

->select  `databasesecrets` from left menu

->hover on secret and click on show button

Answer (score -1):

[image]You can find the Firebase Default path as shown by the arrow.
By default it is "null" so the code would look like:

```
const DEFAULT_PATH = '/null';
```

The DFAULT_TOKEN as described by B. Desai